# displaying the result of xsl in cusomised format

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below xsl tag

```
<RectypeLegType>
<xsl:value-of select="../@id" />
</RectypeLegType>
```

and there can be two possible out come values of this as shown below..

```
1) <RectypeLegType>fixedLeg_612822</RectypeLegType>
2)<RectypeLegType>floatingLeg_194743</RectypeLegType>
```

but i want this value to be dispalyed as

```
<RectypeLegType>fixedLeg</RectypeLegType>
<RectypeLegType>floatingLeg</RectypeLegType>
```

now please advise how can i achieve this possible outcome i need to do cheanges in my  please advise what changes need to be done

Comment: In future, please try to format your prose with capital letters and full stops. It saves everyone a lot of effort, and makes it much more likely you will get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the underscore will always exist in the id attribute:

```
<RectypeLegType>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(../@id, '_')" />
</RectypeLegType>
```